# Split a String and save it

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a String in the following format;

```
NSString *string1 = @"123 ki net 235 lk";
```

I need to format the above String and save it in 2 Strings;

```
NSString *Start, *end;
```

These strings should have the out put

```
String = 123 ki

end = 235 lk
```

Basically, i want to do is, to split the string so the final output will be `123 ki` and `235 lk`. How can i do this ?

Comment: Read the NSString spec.  It's all there.

Comment: What are the parameters of what you want to split? Will the first one always end in ki and the second in lk? Split it in 2 before and after the word "net"? How you do this depends a lot on what situations the code needs to handle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `componentsSeparatedByString`

Example:

```
NSArray* split  = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString: @" net "];

Start = [split objectAtIndex:0];
end = [split objectAtIndex:[split count]-1];
```